# generate treeview nodes programmatically

Tags: c#, treeview

How can I generate treeview nodes programmatically for this collection

```
node id          parent node id

-------          --------------

100                 null           //this is the root node

101                 100

123                 101

124                 101

126                 101

103                 100

104                 100

109                 100

128                 109

122                 100

127                 122

129                 127

130                 129
```

Comment: What is the real issue? You don't know how to make the nodes programmatically or is there something special with the node ids?

Comment: i dont how,it seems i need to make a Recursive method but i dont know how to apply it,i started by add in  collection of nodes but my problem is with the number of these instances!

Answer (score 3):

Here is some pseudo-code that might help to get you started

```
AddChildNodes(TreeNode parentNode)
{
   var childNodeIds GetChildNodeIds(parentNode.Id);
   foreach (int childNodeId in childNodeIds)
   {
      TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode();
      //set other properties...

      //add to parent          
      parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);

      //call same function recursively
      AddChildNodes(childNode);
   }
```

}

Then in your program you get started by getting all items without parent node id (root nodes), creating a node for them and then calling the recursive function above.

Comment: it didnt work,because i dont only have a parent and child,i hav sub children (root ,child 1,child 2 child 3 child 4)my problem is with the number of children cause im filling my treeview from the data base and this table is an output from a storedprocedure

Comment: This algorithm is recursive, it should take care of that as well, no matter how many levels you have. Just use this code and the list you provided and make a simulation on a piece of paper, and you will see it works.

Comment: ya ya i got that,but some values get lost,im gonna hav to fix sm stuff

Comment: If values are being lost you have a bug in the implementation, it doesnt mean the algorithm is wrong. Have you even tried to implement it as I suggested to you?

Comment: whats up people!!im doing it,i told u im gonna hav to fix sm stuff in my code!!

Comment: heyyyy thank u thank u thank u,i solved my problem,your answer was very helpful thx alot